# Will my car be affected by the cold winter temperature?

Tags: car, gasoline, temperature, winter, cold

As winter comes the temperature will get colder and colder. Will this affect my car? I want to be prepared for any problems that will cause any start up problems or driving problems.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Tires will get stiff, will take longer to get heat from the radiator to warm the interior, steering wheel and seats will be colder. Fuel/air mixture will be adjusted to counteract the thicker/denser air.  I believe fuel blend itself is also changed for winter by the distributor.  I notice in my turbo-diesel that my fuel economy (mpg) drops until the engine warms up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe most importantly the battery performance degrades as its temperature drops.

So, lower battery output combined with a cold engine, thicker oil etc and the starting task is much harder...